# Using LoadControl without a Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I load a control without a Page?

```
public void Something()
{
    var ascx = /*LoadControl*/("my.ascx"); // being Page = null
    var ctl1 = ascx.Controls[0];
    var ctl2 = ascx.Controls[1];
}
```

my.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" %>
<asp:Literal ID="ctl1" runat="server" />
<asp:Label ID="ctl2" runat="server" />
```

Comment: I do have `HttpContext.Current` if that is useful somehow...

Comment: Do you mind if I ask what the purpose of this is for?  Have you considered a different approach?

Comment: I have to load all controls from an ASCX. My code works when the Page object exists. But in this case my control is in a context where there isn't a page, and for some reason it doesn't work. (It is the edit mode of Telerik's Sitefinity). My code uses BuilderManager to create a instance from a virtual path, maybe if I load it some other way it may work...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get your Page-Object from HttpContext in this way:

```
Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
if (page != null)
{
     // Use page instance to load your Usercontrol
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use this method, but from the global.asax file in Application_Start? I don't believe global will cast to a Page.

Comment: Why do you neeed a page-instance on Application_Start, what is called only once in an application lifetime?

Comment: I was trying to load UserControls at Application startup and execute their code. It was a pseudo plugin mechanism.

Answer (score 3):

You can always create a new instance of a page if you don't have one:

```
(Page ?? new Page()).LoadControl(...)
```

Answer (score -1):

LoadControl isn't a method of Page, it's a method of the Control class.

You can just use LoadControl() in your control instead of Page.LoadControl()

Comment: LoadControl is defined in the TemplateControl class. It is available to the Page and UserControl classes, but not to Control (or CompositeControl).